# Compound Operators with T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, operators

```
USE Saleslogix
DECLARE @AssumedGrowth int
SET @AssumedGrowth = 28

SELECT
   account,
   employees as NumberIn2013,
   @AssumedGrowth += employees as NumberIn2014
FROM sysdba.account
WHERE employees <> 'NULL'
  and account like 'Shaw%'
```

It's telling me that `+=` is invalid and only works with `+`. Can someone help me with getting this example to work as a compound operator? I don't know if it makes too much difference, but I am using 2005 Management Studio.

Also if it's not a huge pain, adding the same example with `@AssumedGrowth` being a percentage?

Comment: @BAdmin when editing, please note that inline code spans (`like this`) are only meant for parts of code (such as variable names) within sentences, not for highlighting or other emphasis. For example, `@AssumedGrowth` is okay, but not `2005 Management Studio`. Thanks!

Comment: Do you really mean `<> 'NULL'`? You may mean `IS NOT NULL`

Comment: So to clarify - you want a running total in each row, starting from 28, and for the `@AssumedGrowth` variable to remain set to the total afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is this:

```
SELECT account, employees as NumberIn2013,
       (@AssumedGrowth = @AssumedGroup + employees) as NumberIn2014
FROM sysdba.account
WHERE employees <> 'NULL' and account like 'Shaw%';
```

But, I don't think it will work.  I would instead suggest using the built-in capabilities, in particular, `row_number()`:

```
SELECT account, employees as NumberIn2013,
       employees * pow(1 + @AssumedGrowth/100.0, row_number() over (order by <field>) - 1)
FROM sysdba.account
WHERE employees <> 'NULL' and account like 'Shaw%';
```

Note that you need to specify the ordering for the results.  Presumably, there is some sort of `id` or `datetime` column that has the appropriate order.  Tables represent *unordered* sets, so there is no "first" row.